# Install wordpress on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, ubuntu

I am trying to install wordpress on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I have an issue. I am doing everything, step by step.

I installed these things and I've checked status as well:

- Apache ( status is active )
- Mysql   ( status is active )
- PHP      ( PHP 5.6.38-3+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 )

When I'm opening webrowser firefox with http://localhost/ I have an error:

> "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress"

What should I check? I checked another topic but its not help me.

Comment: `phpinfo()` and check mysql extension is installed and enabled

Comment: As suggested by Masivuye Cokile , you can put <? phpinfo(); ?> in a file index.php, which you put at the location pointed out by http://localhost

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you installed MySQL itself but not the php extension.

Try something like: `sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql`

Comment: And btw, PHP 5.6 is quite old, any reason why you don't use PHP 7.x already?

Comment: I added phpinfo(); in test.php file. I run this command: sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql I restarted Ubuntu and I have still the same error. I have to use PHP 5.6 because I need to test something in this version not higher.

Comment: Still looks that something with your used PHP version causes this error. Could you try to install the specif extension for PHP 5. `sudo apt install php5-mysql`

Comment: And make sure to restart apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: I have restarted apache service few times during tests it changes nothing.

Comment: @stardustsky Did you saw my previous comment? Did you tried installing `php5-mysql` instead of `php-mysql`?

Comment: yes, I tried  installing php5-mysql but it changes nothing.

Comment: As for me, after installing `php` (which is `v7.2` in my case), I had to specify the exact versions `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.2 php7.2-mysql`.